# Compilation Error :CS1705 when trying to implement KENDO UI in MVC2

Tags: c#, kendo-ui

[image]

I am using KENDO UI first time. Trying to implement with MVC 2. But got above error. My doubt whether Kendo UI support for MVC 2 ??

Comment: The error seems to suggest that it doesn't support MVC2. At least not the binary version. Try to download the sources and compile it yourself :-)

Comment: @RuneGrimstad thanks.. now im trying kendo ui trail version.. want to purchase full version depending upon it support in MVC 2.. want to know whether any way is there to make kendo ui work in MVC 2.

Answer (score 4):

As you can see on [this page](http://www.kendoui.com/server-wrappers.aspx), Kendo UI with ASP.NET MVC Wrapper support ASP.NET MVC 3+. Not MVC2. You have to update your project

Comment: thanqs lot.. whether kendo ui work in normal .aspx and .cs rather then mvc ? or want to follow oly mvc pattern to implement kendo UI ??

Comment: KendoUI for ASP.NET MVC is build for ASP.NET MVC. If you want to use Telerik for an ASP.NET project, you can use KendoUI JS library or RadControls for ASP.NET Ajax http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you would've copied and pasted the error text instead of a screenshot it would've been easier to read, but the error clearly states that Kendo.MVC relies on MVC 3, but found MVC 2.

Comment: thanks i will update to MVC 3 soon but now im trying kendo ui trail version.. want to purchase full version depending upon it support in MVC 2.. want to know whether any way is there to make kendo ui work in MVC 2.